# ReadOnly Session is writable

Tags: asp.net, session, concurrency, webforms, session-variables

In out project we need to execute a few AJAX calls in a row asynchronously, so the next call doesn't have to wait for previous to return. And even though client issues calls asynchronously, server processes them sequentially due to Session lock.

Since we don't need to modify Session in these calls, we marked page that AJAX calls with `EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"`via @Page directive. And it worked, calls became truly async and no longer depend on each other timing. But what we found out - in that backend code Session is writable despite being marked as ReadOnly. We can assign values to Session and the values persist. Is this a bug or behavior by design?

Comment: What session state mode are you using (InProc, StateServer, SQLServer, Custom)?

Comment: @MichaelLiu basic InProc. Does it matter? Shouldn't read-only always mean read-only?

Comment: It will probably work as you expect for StateServer and SQLServer, but if you use InProc, it's your responsibility to make sure session isn't updated if it's marked read-only. InProc (unlike StateServer and SQLServer) doesn't make a copy of the session state for each request, so ASP.NET has no way of detecting or preventing changes to objects.

Comment: @MichaelLiu makes sense. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this behavior is a "by design" gotcha of in-process session state (which, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be well documented).

#### Out-of-Process Session State (State Server or SQL Server)

At the beginning of every request, ASP.NET loads and deserializes session data from external storage into memory. Each request gets its own copy of the data, so changes to the data won't affect other concurrent requests in the same session.

if EnableSessionState is set to ReadOnly, then at the end of the request, the data are simply discarded rather than serialized back to external storage.

#### In-Process Session State

No serialization or deserialization occurs. Instead, there's a single set of session data in memory which lives for the duration of the session. Each request in the same session shares that set of data, and changes to the data are **immediately** visible to other concurrent requests.

I suppose the ASP.NET team *could* have made Session read only when EnableSessionState is set to ReadOnly:

```
this.Session["Customer"] = customer; // Why not throw InvalidOperationException?
```

But ASP.NET would still have no way of detecting changes to the objects themselves:

```
Customer customer = (Customer)this.Session["Customer"];
customer.Address = address; // ASP.NET can't detect this.
```

Therefore, **it's your responsibility as a developer to avoid changing session data** if you set EnableSessionState to ReadOnly. Otherwise, you may introduce multithreading bugs.